# Summernote insertText, ошибка: context.invoke is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице несколько textarea, в модальном окне выбирается ссылка и втавляется в textarea, но проблема что вставляется всегда в первую, а не в ту что нужна, в общем не пойму как отловить текущую textarea, сам код

```
$(document).on('click', '.pdf-item', function(context) {      
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  $('#PdfModal').modal('hide');  
  $('#PdfModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (context) {
    context.invoke('editor.insertText', '[pdf url=]');
  });   
});
```

Получаю

> context.invoke is not a function

Версия [summernote](http://summernote.org/) последняя на данный момент - 0.7.1

Comment: А если курсор поместить в другое поле?

Comment: получаю тоже самое